# How to find an matching element (either number or string) in a multi level cell?

Tags: matlab, cell-array

I am trying to search a cell of cell arrays for a matching number (for example, `2`) or string (`'text'`). Example for a cell:

```
 A = {1 {2; 3};4 {5 'text' 7;8 9 10}};
```

[There is similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30038476/how-to-find-an-element-in-a-complex-cell). However, this solution works only, if you want to find a number value in cell. I would need a solution as well for numbers as for strings.
The needed output should be 1 or 0 (the value is or is not in the cell `A`) and the cell level/deepness where the matched element was found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your example input, you can match character vectors as well as numbers by replacing `ismember` in the [linked solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30039737/24447) with `isequal`. You can get the depth at which the search value was found by tracking how many times the function has to go round the `while` loop.

```
function [isPresent, depth] = is_in_cell(cellArray, value)

    depth = 1;
    f = @(c) isequal(value, c);
    cellIndex = cellfun(@iscell, cellArray);
    isPresent = any(cellfun(f, cellArray(~cellIndex)));

    while ~isPresent
        depth = depth + 1;
        cellArray = [cellArray{cellIndex}];
        cellIndex = cellfun(@iscell, cellArray);
        isPresent = any(cellfun(f, cellArray(~cellIndex)));
        if ~any(cellIndex)
            break
        end
    end

end
```

Using `isequal` works because `f` is only called for elements of `cellArray` that are not themselves cell arrays. Use `isequaln` if you want to be able to search for `NaN` values.

Note this now won't search *inside* numeric, logical or string arrays:

```
>> A = {1 {2; 3};4 {5 'text' 7;8 9 [10 11 12]}};
>> is_in_cell(A, 10)
ans =
  logical
   0
```

If you want that, you can define `f` as

```
f = @(c) isequal(value, c) || isequal(class(value), class(c)) && ismember(value, c);
```

which avoids calling `ismember` with incompatible data types, because of the 'short-circuiting' behaviour of `||` and `&&`. This last solution is still a bit inconsistent in how it matches strings with character vectors, just in case that's important to you - see if you can figure out how to fix that.